# How to find the urdf of kinect v2?

Tags: kinect, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Where can I find and how can I add a urdf file of the kinect v2 to urdf of my robot?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242286/how-to-find-the-urdf-of-kinect-v2?/) by [78226415](https://answers.ros.org/users/27677/78226415/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may refer to this

https://github.com/code-iai/iai_robots/blob/master/iai_kinect2_description/urdf/kinect2.urdf.xacro

---

EDIT

The `URDF` of kinect is just for displaying in RViz or Gazebo, in my opinion. The only thing meaningful is the tf `base_link->kinect2_frame`. The complicated kinect1.urdf is just for good-looking.

Well, I think someone will perfect it someday.

---

Originally posted by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) with karma: 763 on 2016-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [78226415](https://answers.ros.org/users/27677/78226415/) on 2016-08-24**:
Thank you very much!

**Comment by [78226415](https://answers.ros.org/users/27677/78226415/) on 2016-08-24**:
I have a look at it, the kinect2.urdf.xacro file is very simple, only one link,like:

I don't know whether it is good enough to build a model for a robot.
The urdf of kinect1 in turtlebot project is not so simple.

**Comment by [78226415](https://answers.ros.org/users/27677/78226415/) on 2016-09-22**:
@shay, I have a look at the link you provided, it have been updated, it is good for using in robot model now. Thank you all the same!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well,I make a complete kinectv2 model and hope this will help you.
https://github.com/wangxian4423/kinect_v2_udrf

[image: kinect v2]

---

Originally posted by [winds W](https://answers.ros.org/users/41366/winds-w/) with karma: 11 on 2019-05-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1